# How to run multiple macros on multiple cell change events in a single worksheet by calling multiple macro functions

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet and I want to call multiple subs on multiple cell change events and cell.

In this worksheet, `Range("K3")` and `Range("K32")` are formula cells and I want to call `calculation()` for `Range("K3")` and `calculation1()` for `Range("K32")`.

Please guide. Thanks

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Static MyOldVal
Static MyOldVal1
If Range("K3").Value <> MyOldVal Then
Call calculation

Else
If Cells(32, 11).Value <> MyOldVal1 Then Call calculation1

MyOldVal = Range("K3").Value
MyOldVal1 = Range("K32").Value

End If
End Sub

Private Sub calculation()
Cells(4, 10) = (Cells(11, 8) + Cells(16, 8) + Cells(28, 7) + (351 * Cells(25, 3))) / 0.9 / 0.7 * 1.2
Cells(5, 10) = (Cells(11, 8) + Cells(16, 8) + Cells(28, 7) + (351 * Cells(25, 3))) / 0.7 / 0.7 * 1.2
End Sub

Private Sub calculation1()
Cells(33, 10) = (Cells(40, 8) + Cells(45, 8) + Cells(57, 7) + (351 * Cells(54, 3))) / 0.9 / 0.7 * 1.2
Cells(34, 10) = (Cells(40, 8) + Cells(45, 8) + Cells(57, 7) + (351 * Cells(54, 3))) / 0.7 / 0.7 * 1.2
End Sub
```

Comment: `worksheet_change` event?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this for example:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Static dict As Object   'stored cell addresses and associated cell values
    Dim arrRanges, addr, v
    
    arrRanges = Array("K3", "K32") 'the cells to be monitored

    If dict Is Nothing Then        'first call?  Set up ranges and values
        Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        For Each addr In arrRanges
            dict(addr) = Me.Range(addr).Value 'initial values
        Next addr
    Else              'not the first call: compare old vs. new values
        On Error Goto haveError
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'disable events
        For Each addr In arrRanges
            v = Me.Range(addr).Value
            If dict(addr) <> v Then      'value has changed ?
                Debug.Print addr, "old:" & dict(addr), "new:" & v
                Select Case addr         'which cell has changed?
                    Case "K3": calculation
                    Case "K32": calculation1
                End Select
                dict(addr) = v           'store new value?
            End If
        Next addr
    End If
haveError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True 're-enable events

End Sub
```

**EDIT**: here's a version using a hidden sheet

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim arrRanges, addr, v, wsStore As Worksheet, cStore As Range, vOld
    
    Set wsStore = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Store") 'hidden sheet
    arrRanges = Array("K3", "K32") 'the cells to be monitored
    
    On Error GoTo haveError
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'disable events
    For Each addr In arrRanges
        v = Me.Range(addr).Value
        Set cStore = wsStore.Range(addr)
        vOld = cStore.Value
        If v <> vOld Then 'value has changed ?
            Debug.Print addr, "old:" & vOld, "new:" & v
            Select Case addr         'which cell has changed?
                Case "K3": Calculation
                Case "K32": calculation1
            End Select
            cStore.Value = v        'store new value
        End If
    Next addr
    
haveError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True 're-enable events
End Sub
```

Comment: I had try to run a this, When I am changing values of "K3", ```calculation()``` is working fine but when I am trying to change "K32" for ```calculation1()```, its showing an error of "Run-time error '28'; Out of stack space". Kind guidance needed.

Comment: My mistake - try with the edits above.  Updating the sheet may trigger another calculation so you need to avoid getting stuck in an endless loop.

Comment: Thankyou, Its working very fine now. Can you please suggest a solution regarding `If dict Is Nothing Then` because whenever a user opens an excel sheet and change a value, `private sub calculation` is not triggered immediately until user had to change a value 2 to 3 times.

Comment: If you want to store the values between sessions then you can do something like write them into cells on a hidden sheet, otherwise it's not possible to avoid the first calculation needing to fill the dictionary.

Comment: Okay. Let's suppose I have another hidden sheet named "hidden" and write a random value "54" in cell "J1", so how do I add a code so it won't populate dictionary each time when I reopen a workbook ? Or please suggest a solution so a user don't need to put value 3 to 4 times to get reflected values in main sheet. 

Cooperation would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Will `dict.add "foo"`
`Set getmydictionary = dict`
`If getmydictionary.exists("foo") Then calculation` will work ?

Comment: You could add `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("namHere").Calculate` to the workbook_open event and that should initialize the dictionary when the user first open the workbook.  If that's not acceptable then skip the dictionary alltogether and just compare the cell values with the values on the hidden sheet.